# How to fix the invalid JSON in my case?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I have an invalid json stringify data came back from the postgres database.

It's a invalid string and the data is like

```
{"{\"title\":\"john\"}","{\"tel\":\"12345\"}"}
```

In my code, I use the following to make it valid:

```
var newJson = '"' + mydata.info.replace(/","/g, ",").replace(/^{"/, "[").replace(/"}$/, "]") + '"';
```

However, when I do `JSON.parse(newJson)`, it still gave me string instead of an object.

The newJson value is like the following after the replace methods

```
console.log(newJson) =>  "["{\"title\":\"john\"},{\"tel\":\"12345\"}"]"
```

The funny thing is if I specify it directly like:

```
newJson =  "["{\"title\":\"john\"},{\"tel\":\"12345\"}"]"
newJson = JSON.parse(newJson)

console.log(typeof newJson) => object
```

it will actually gave me an object.

I have been trying to fight this invalid json for hours and really don't know what else I can do. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are possibly encoding original data twice (something now shown in the code you've shared). You should never manipulate standard data formats with string manipulation functions.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using a `json[]` (aka. an array of `json`) type in Postgres? Because that's how your output looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data that's saved inside the DB like suggested in the comments, the data is json-encoded multiple times.

If that's really not possible you can try to read it with something like this (untested):

```
// First replace the first and last {} with []
var arrStr = '[' + json.substring(1, json.length - 1) + ']';
// Parse it as an array of strings
var arr = JSON.parse(arrStr);
// Cycle every item in the array and parse it
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    results.push(JSON.parse(arr[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newJson))
```

Try use this